# How can I change the GrayLevel?

Tags: plotting

I am using the GreyLevel

```
  ContourPlot[-p1 Log[p1] - 
  p2 Log[p2] - (1 - p2 - p1) Log[(1 - p2 - p1)] + 
  Log[p1^2 + p2^2 + (1 - p2 - p1)^2], {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

I get

[image]
How can I change the black and white role? I want to reverse the black and white.

Comment: `ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1 - #] &)`

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides of `ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1 - #] &)`, another way maybe `ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}]`

```
ContourPlot[-p1 Log[p1] - 
  p2 Log[p2] - (1 - p2 - p1) Log[(1 - p2 - p1)] + 
  Log[p1^2 + p2^2 + (1 - p2 - p1)^2], {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}]]
```

[image]